# Git: printing unchanged lines from specific file in HEAD

Tags: git

Is there a git/binutil command that could print the unchanged lines from a file in the HEAD ?

For example, let's say that I changed 1 line in the `user/howard.yml`

```
name: Howard Silk
-area: Interface
+area: Strategy
```

The command shall give me only the line that didn't changed

```
name: Howard Silk
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit more? Are you trying to revert the changes in the checkout-out working tree? Or do you want create a new commit with only specific changes included?

Comment: I've added an example of what I don't want. Not sure if it's any clearer :s

Comment: Still not quite sure I get you. As I understand now you basically want to see the output of e.g. `git diff HEAD -- howard.yml` but without any lines added and/or removed i.e. you want to see only unchanged lines in of the diff/commit?

Comment: Exactly ! I updated the question with your phrasing. Sorry for my shaky english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `git` command that would do this directly but one way to do this might be:

```sh
git diff HEAD -U9999 -- user/howard.yml | grep '^ '
```

- `git diff HEAD -- user/howard.yml` will output the difference between the worktree and `HEAD` in file `user/howard.yml`
- `-U` specifies the lines of context, i.e. unchanged lines, around the changes. `9999` is just an arbitrarily big number to print *all lines of the file*
- `grep '^ '` will then display only the lines starting (`^`) with a space character, i.e. the unchanged lines (added lines have a `+`, removed lines a `-` instead of the space)

Be aware that this will output all the unchanged lines **with** the prefixed space. If you want the lines exactly as in the file you'll still have to remove the space e.g. with

```sh
git diff HEAD -U9999 -- user/howard.yml | grep '^ ' | sed 's/^ //'
```

Comment: `git diff etc | sed -n 's/^ //p'`